# SPLIT Week between months

Tags: sql, split, hana, dayofweek

Requirement is to split weeks between Months i.e. TECHNICAL_WEEK. populate tech week as Monday date but If month within the same week then populate 1st day of month and remaining days in week with e the 1st day of month. the Next week should be populated as Monday date.

Please help to build a HANA SQL
Example result below

```
DAY          -------        TECH_WEEK  
20230529     -------        20230529  
20230530     -------        20230529  
20230531     -------        20230529  
20230601     -------        20230601    
20230602     -------        20230601  
20230603     -------        20230601    
20230604     -------        20230601
```

Comment: A work week Starts Monday.  However, when a month begins within a work week, the work week is divided into two technical weeks. The first technical week includes the last few days of the previous month, while the second technical week includes the first few days of the new month. The workweeks then continue from Monday until an end of the month forces another set of technical weeks. For instance, if a month starts on a Wednesday, the first technical week will be Monday and Tuesday of the old month, and the second technical week Wednesday thru Sunday of the new month. (*Is this what you mean?*)

Comment: Yes Paul , that's my requirement.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take some example data:

```
SELECT GENERATED_PERIOD_START DAY
FROM SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '2023-01-01', '2024-01-01')
```

As per my understanding of your requirement, this statement should do the job:

```
SELECT 
    DAY, add_days(DAY, -1 * CASE WHEN dayofmonth(day) - 1 < weekday(day) THEN dayofmonth(day) - 1 ELSE weekday(day) END) TECH_WEEK
FROM
(
    SELECT GENERATED_PERIOD_START DAY
    FROM SERIES_GENERATE_DATE('INTERVAL 1 DAY', '2023-01-01', '2024-01-01')
)
```